# Specify a list of strings as a function param types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm trying to define a list of `str` as a type for a function param but I don't know how to do this

I know that python allows you to define functions specifying the type of value expected by the function params. Example:

```
def f(param: str):
    print(type(param))
```

But I don't know is how is this annotation called `param: str`, therefore is pretty hard to find documentation on this. Also I understand that is only an aesthetic in code documentation and not some kind of type enforcement for the params.

Could you help me with a way to define a list of `str` and the name of this annotation?

For a more clear example of what I want in **TypeScript** it would be written this way

```
function func(param: string[]) {}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) has `List` for this purpose

```
from typing import List

def f(param: List[str]):
    pass
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you so much.

Also for anyone who is interested in the python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @NicolasCardenas do you know if you can put List of a List as typing ?

Comment: `List` is deprecated, use `list` instead. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List